# How did Ragetti escape if he was captured at the end of the 1st movie?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean

In the **1st movie** Ragetti (the man with the wooden eye) is

> captured after he surrended, when the curse of the Black Pearl was lifted, in the battle of Isla de Muerta, aboard the HMS Dauntless.

After the ship got back to Port Royale, they should have been all hanged next to or after Jack Sparrow for piracy.

In the **2nd movie** we see him and Pintel arrive in a rowboat to

> the cannibals' island and try to unground the Black Pearl.

Is there any explanation for how they escaped hanging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The escape of Pintel (the scowling one) and Ragetti (the single-wooden-eyed one) is detailed in the (fittingly-named) comic: [*The Escape of Pintel and Ragetti!*](https://pirates.fandom.com/wiki/The_Escape_of_Pintel_and_Ragetti!).

It was originally published by Disney Adventures as a tie-in for the action figure line created by Zizzle. Originally the comic used action figures as the characters, but was later released in classic drawn cartoon form under the title *Jailbreak*.

I managed to track down a version of the comic [*Jailbreak*](https://damailbox.tumblr.com/post/653165764297244672/pirates-of-the-caribbean-jailbreak-disney) thanks to a Tumblr blog dedicated to the Disney Adventures magazine.

In it we see that Pintel and Ragetti escape thanks to the lovable jailhouse dog; who just wants to have some mutton but is rudely shooed away by one of the guards. The dog steals the keys to the cell and drops them in the cell. They attempt to sneak out without alerting the guards, but it goes slightly awry.

[image]

<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

After falling into a cart and rolling down a hill the men, along with the dog, fall into a rowboat and successfully manage to row away from the prison guards giving chase. The comic ends with the two men and the dog sitting in the rowboat

[image]

<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>